# Why is ‘I recommend her to speak to a lawyer’ wrong?

Tags: meaning, subjunctive-mood

> 1. We'd recommend you to book your flight early.
> 2. Students are recommended to make an appointment with a counselor.

are correct, while

> 3. I recommend her to speak to a lawyer.

is wrong.

Why is the third sentence wrong?

Comment: Actually none of your examples are correct.

Comment: You might want to check out [ell.se].